# How can I select multiple value in dropdown at one time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My code is:

```
 <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
             <li class="week" ><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox"> Monaday</label></div></li>
             <li class="week" ><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox"> Tuesday</label></div></li>
             <li class="week" ><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox"> Wednesday</label></div></li>
             <li class="week" ><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox"> Thusday</label></div></li>
             <li class="week" ><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox"> Friday</label></div></li>
             <li class="week" ><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox"> Saturday</label></div></li>
             <li class="week" ><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox"> Sunday</label></div></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
```

I want to create a drop down menu in which `multiple check-boxes` selected by user at a time, but when I am going to select one then drop down becomes closed.

Comment: why not use a SELECT element with multiple attribute?

Comment: why not using a `select` with attribute `multiple`?

Comment: Could you post the dropdown code?

Comment: This might help you. [Visit this demo](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/) And [Document](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget)

Comment: You can use Multiple select box. Check this [link](http://loudev.com/#demos)

Answer (score 3):

i am assuming you are using `bootstrap`...check this link, they have defined how to select `multiple-values` in a drop down  [**Link Here**](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)  , please check **3rd example** in this!!

Comment: Yes i am using but not working in my code. which link is important for this

Comment: I think i have any link problem of js and css. can you pls tell me which link is necessary for this select

Comment: @user3102009 : there is a `zip` file download link through which u cn download and add the files, for `bootstrap` files, i'll suggest to include file through cdn as shown @ http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dropdown with check boxes where multiple check boxes can be selected by user then use this jquery plugin.

Demo:     http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/

Tutorial: http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

check this as well: https://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a HTML *select* element which is native and designed for the purpose, with the *multiple* attribute - see [<select> on the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select).

This would look something like-

```
<select multiple class="dropdown-menu">
    <option value="monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="thursday">Thursday</option>
    <option value="friday">Friday</option>
    <option value="saturday">Saturday</option>
    <option value="sunday">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

I've created a [jsfiddle showing](http://jsfiddle.net/pwdst/w2Ptv/) a working example.

Credit to A.Wolff for being the first to suggest this (if you'd added it as an answer I'd be voting it up).

Lastly, you have a few typos in your example weekdays.